# want to run command from outside Postgresql and want to store password in encrypted format?

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a script that will check whether replication is on or not, so I wrote the command in a script:- PGPASSWORD='********' psql -U user_name -p 54032 -c "select * from pg_stat_replication" -d postgres

but I want to encrypt the password for security purposes so I did MD5 encryption and put the hash of it.
PGPASSWORD='a67a4e657061eac2036a88ec523dbbbb' psql -U user_name -p 54032 -c "select * from pg_stat_replication" -d postgres

It's not working Please help me.

Comment: Why just change the password to 'a67a4e657061eac2036a88ec523dbbbb' if you want to use that string to log on with?

Comment: And how would that help? If the hashed password worked then someone having it would be no different then having the clear text password.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid having a clear text password somewhere, either on the command line or in the environment or in a password file.

If you want to authenticate without a clear text password anywhere, use certificate authentication with a client certificate.